# Flutter: How do you change the AppBar Title font?

Tags: flutter, dart, text, appbar

Here's my first flutter app... Just learning and messing around a bit. I'm trying to figure out how to change the text of the title within the AppBar. Note that the text in the body changes, but the text in the app bar does not. Am I totally wrong here? I used this method based on other public questions on stack overflow on this topic. No luck on my end.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('My First App', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Audowide'),),
      centerTitle: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.cyan[700],
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: Text("Body Text!",
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontFamily: 'Audiowide',
          letterSpacing: 2.0,
          color: Colors.grey[500],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {}, // for later use
      backgroundColor: Colors.cyan[700],
      child: Text("Press"),
    ),
  ),
));
```

Comment: Are you sure the font family of the body Text widget is changing ?

Comment: Make sure Autowide font is actually defined in pubspec.yaml and is corresponding to the .tff/.otf file you have got.

Comment: It was all good other than my typo! Silly me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 1: Fix typo in your code change `Audowide` to `Audiowide` 
Step 2: Download https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Audiowide 
Step 3: Put file in directory `assets/fonts`
Step 4: In `pubspec.yaml`

```
fonts:
  - family: Audiowide
    fonts:
      - asset: assets/fonts/Audiowide-Regular.ttf
```

[image]

working demo

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the font, and put your reference in pubspec.yaml.
Look at how the documentation reports:
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts

Comment: That was already done, as I noted that the text changed in the body part just not the title. Ty for the assistance. I had a typo .

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the 2 things:

1. Adding fonts manually to the project and defining them in `pubspec.yaml`, before using them in the project.
2. Another interesting package is `google_fonts` which is simpler and provides options for a lot many fonts that you might wanna try. The entire procedure to add it to your project and subsequent use is [here](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts)

Comment: Ty for the input! It was a typo! Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Google Font in your `pubspec.yaml` file.

```
dependencies:
  google_fonts: ^1.1.1
```

Import the dependency in the `Pubspec.yaml` file

```
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
```